# Use custom HttpMessageHandler with different configurations

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I have a custom `HttpMessageHandler` implementation:

```cs
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly MyHandlerOptions _config;

    public MyHandler(
        HttpClient httpClient,
        IOptions<MyHandlerOptions> options)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _config = options.Value;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = await GetAccessToken()
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        //some logic to get access token using _httpClient and _config
    }

}
```

It requires confiuration object `MyHandlerOptions`. Its form is not so important here. It basically contains clientId, clientSecret, etc. that are needed for the handler to know how to get the access token.

I have a few services (typed http clients) that need to use `MyHandler`:

```cs
//registration of MyHandler itself
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyHandler>();

//configuration of MyHandler
builder.Services.AddOptions<MyHandlerOptions>()
.Configure<IConfiguration>((config, configuration) =>
{
    configuration.GetSection("MyHandlerOptions").Bind(config);
});

//Services that need to use MyHandler:
services.AddHttpClient<Service1>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<Service2>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<Service3>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyHandler>();
```

The problem is that the `MyHandlerOptions` instance that I registered is valid only when used with `Service1`. However, `Service2` and `Service3` require other configuration (different clientId, clientSecret, etc.). How can I achieve it?

**The possible solution that comes to my mind:**

1. Create a new service:

```cs
public class AccessTokenGetter 
{
    Task<string> GetAccessToken(AccessTokenConfig config) 
    {
        //get the access token...
    }
}
```

2. Create separate `HttpMessageHandler`s for each case where configuration is different:

```cs
public class MyHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly MyHandler1Options _config;
    private readonly AccessTokenGetter _accessTokenGetter;

    public MyHandler(AccessTokenGetter accessTokenGetter, IOptions<MyHandlerOptions1> options)
    {
        _accessTokenGetter = accessTokenGetter;
        _config = options.Value;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //somehow convert _config to AccessTokenConfig
        request.Headers.Authorization = await _accessTokenGetter.GetAccessToken(_config)
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class MyHandler2 : DelegatingHandler
{
    //same implementation as MyHandler1, just use MyHandler2Options instead
}
```

3. Register my services:

```cs
//configurations
builder.Services.AddOptions<MyHandler1Options>()
.Configure<IConfiguration>((config, configuration) =>
{
    configuration.GetSection("MyHandler1Options").Bind(config);
});

builder.Services.AddOptions<MyHandler2Options>()
.Configure<IConfiguration>((config, configuration) =>
{
    configuration.GetSection("MyHandler2Options").Bind(config);
});

//AccessTokenGetter
services.AddHttpClient<AccessTokenGetter>()

//Services that need to use MyHandlers:
services.AddHttpClient<Service1>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyHandler1>();
services.AddHttpClient<Service2>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyHandler2>();
services.AddHttpClient<Service3>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyHandler2>();
```

Is there a better solution? I am not a great fan of my idea, it is not very flexible.

Answer (score 5):

```
services.AddHttpClient<Service1>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => 
    {
         var handler = sp.GetRequiredService<MyHandler>();
         handler.Foo = "Bar";
         return handler;
    });

services.AddHttpClient<Service2>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => 
    {
         var handler = sp.GetRequiredService<MyHandler>();
         handler.Foo = "Baz";
         return handler;
    });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.
Should be marked as the answer.